Is parquet suitable as a format to store high frequency IoT applications?
As absurd as it may sound, I am considering Parquet as a candidate storage format to persist live data ingested from heterogeneous sensors for large scale IoT applications. Currently, the system uses Postgres to store all the ingested data, however it gets extremely slow as the data volume increases.

The data is highly structured and will follow a well defined schema consisting of several tables
The type of queries could be both analytical and transactional. However, the system would be mostly used for analytical querying
The expected total data size will keep growing as the sensor frequency could be 30-60Hz (for example it may hit 300GB within a month).
The data should allow any type of SQL querying (it will be exposed an OData service)
The data will be seldom updated because the user would not want to mess around with the sensor readings. Other tables that store metadata such as Sensor information, Location information might be updated at times but the frequency is too low for such updates.
To summarize, its a high frequency write + read application, but there shouldn't be two processes writing to the same data at a time thus concurrency may not be an issue

If I use Parquet, I will end up with thousands if not millions of files each storing a single record. I will have to organize these files as per the tables they belong to.
But, I think a service that periodically merges all the parquet files (say every 24H) and partitions them based on certain features such as space and time, this will significantly reduce storage costs and query run times as the querying will be done on Parquet directly. The metadata can be used for indexing and filter pushdown will tremendously improve performance.
Now since I am not really an experienced data engineer, I would highly appreciate if I can get a heads up on what could be the possible issues I can face with this design architecture.
